# Client-side change callback route of Developer Express MVC GridView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, gridview, devexpress

Is it possible to change the callback route of a Developer Express GridView on the client side? Or maybe perform a callback to another route rather than the specified at the `settings.CallbackRouteValues` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems its possible, through the GridView's property `callbackUrl`. Just need to set the property before performing the callback:

```
GridViewName.callbackUrl = '/Desired/Route';
```

I also recommend to set this property to it's original value on callback ending, through the End Callback client-side event handler.

Comment: It seems that you are using undocumented API... What are the reasons?

Comment: A bit of despair... I discovered this property with the help of firebug. Maybe is not the right way to do this, and maybe there is not a right way to make a callback to another route, but is the only way I've found so far to accomplish it. I'm currently using DevExpress 2011 v1.7.